# git cherry-pick: output resulting new commit sha

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I am using git cherry-pick as part of a bash script. For reporting purposes, I would like to output the resulting commit SHA of this cherry-picking to the console. However, there seems to be no option in the cherry-pick command that would return the commit SHA.

Is there a way to get the commit SHA of the commit that was created using a cherry-pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `cherry-pick` applies the commit on `HEAD`, you can use the [`rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) command to get the hash of the commit referenced by `HEAD` after cherry-picking:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-ref> && git rev-parse HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git cherry-pick xxx && git log -1 --pretty=%H
```

If `git cherry-pick` succeeds, print the new commit sha1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ElpieKay, this solution also works fine.